# Migrating from Android to iOS AWS IoT

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, credentials, aws-iot

I'm making an IoT client on iOS, and I'm having trouble finding the following methods that exist on Android:

```
AWSIotKeystoreHelper.saveCertificateAndPrivateKey();
keystore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.getIotKeystore();
```

I have a Certificate and Private key in pem format, and I need to generate a keystore (keychain on iOS)

Are there any similar methods in the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWSIoTKeyChain in the AWS IoT SDK for iOS. You can add a certificate to the Keychain using the `addCertificate` method as described in [addCertificate](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSIoT/Internal/AWSIoTKeychain.h#L43,L47). After adding the certificate, you can get it through `getIdentityRef` based on the tag as described in [getIdentityRef](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSIoT/Internal/AWSIoTKeychain.h#L55).

Comment: When I declare `var iotKeychain: AWSIoTKeychain!` I get an error: Use of undeclared type 'AWSIoTKeychain'. I used the `import AWSIoT`, and other classes can be declared just fine, this one is causing an issue.
When I use `AWSIoTKeychain` inside `viewDidLoad()` I get the Use of unresolved identifier 'AWSIoTKeychain' error.